# What is the rational for using char *ch vs char* ch

Tags: c, pointers, coding-style

I most commonly see code with the pointer next to the variable name instead of the type.

I originally preferred the later (·char* ch·) because to me it makes more sense that I am declaring the type as a character pointer and just naming the variable.

That said, I feel like I must be missing something if so many people see it the other way. What are other ways of looking at it that might provide more meaning?

Comment: Because the pointer-decl is married to the *variable*; not the *type*. `int* a,b` does not declare two pointers, though it certainly looks like it would. You can link it to the type using a typedef, `typedef int *intPtr; intPtr a,b;` but *don't*. It will just irk C programmers. We *want* to see the asterisks.

Comment: Very good point WhozCraig. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you write

```
char* ch;
```

or

```
char *ch;
```

does not cause any issues.

However, if you need to declare multiple pointers,

```
char *ch1,*ch2;
```

there is a chance you make a mistake like this,

```
char* ch1,ch2;
```

In this example, `ch1` is a pointer but `ch2` is plain int.

IMHO, it's better to use the * near the variable name to make sure you don't make a similar mistake